# How to clone a react child component and modify its text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

On my Gatsby site, I am using a custom component on MDX pages to showcase commands inside tabs. Most of these commands are similar except the platfrom binary name they use. For example, `kubectl get nodes` (Kubernetes) vs `oc get nodes` (OpenShift). I want to make my component act in such a way that:

1. If only Kubernetes tab exist in MDX file, component should clone the Kuberetes tab and replace `kubectl` with `oc` and the tab tile as OpenShift.
2. If both Kubernetes and OpenShift tabs exist, render as usual.

[image]

Below is the excerpt from my MDX file:

````
<State initialState={{ activeTabIndex: 0 }}>

...

<ColocatedTabs>
  <ColocatedTab label="Kubernetes">

  ```bash
  kubectl get pod
  ```
  </ColocatedTab>
  <ColocatedTab label="OpenShift">

  ```bash
  oc get pod
  ```
  </ColocatedTab>
</ColocatedTabs>

...

(more tabs components)

</State>
````

And here is the component I have:

```
import React from "react";
import { Tabs, TabList, Tab, TabPanels, TabPanel } from "@reach/tabs";
import { Observe } from "mdx-observable";

const CoLocatedTabs = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Observe>
      {({ setState, ...state }) => (
        <Tabs
          index={state.activeTabIndex}
          onChange={newIndex => setState({ activeTabIndex: newIndex })}
        >
          <TabList>
            {React.Children.map(children, child => (
              <Tab>{child.props.label}</Tab>
            ))}
          </TabList>
          <TabPanels>
            {React.Children.map(children, child => (
              <TabPanel>{child.props.children}</TabPanel>
            ))}
          </TabPanels>
        </Tabs>
      )}
    </Observe>
  );
};

export default CoLocatedTabs;
```

I want to modify the componet such that it handles the following:

````
//Case 1: no openshift specific command
<ColocatedTabs>
  <ColocatedTab label="Kubernetes">

  ```bash
  kubectl get pod
  ```
  </ColocatedTab>
</ColocatedTabs>

//Case 2: openshift specific command
<ColocatedTabs>
  <ColocatedTab label="Kubernetes">

  ```bash
  kubectl create ns test
  ```
  </ColocatedTab>
  <ColocatedTab label="OpenShift">

  ```bash
  oc new-project test
  ```
  </ColocatedTab>
</ColocatedTabs>
````

And produces Kubernetes and OpenShift tabs with commands `kubectl get pod` and `oc get pod` respectively for case one. And two tabs as specified for case 2.

Please see the sample code at: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-mdx-tabs-linked-state-demo-1nml6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&initialpath=%2Fmdx-tabs-demo%2F&module=%2Fsrc%2Fpages%2Fmdx-tabs-demo.mdx&theme=dark

Comment: This would be fairly straightforward to hard code with conditionals, but why do you want the result to be the same regardless of what tabs are present? Couldn't you just make sure both tabs are always there if you want them both to be rendered? Just trying to understand your use case, there might be a more efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Yes I agree this could be improved upon. I am using Gatsby for documentation and want to include both Kubernetes and OpenShift commands in step by step instructions. I am a react newbie and not really sure how to tackle this. I'll update the question to include what my final output should be.

Comment: @ChrisB. I have made some updates based on your suggestions, please see https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-modify-1-kzfmq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&initialpath=%2Fmdx-tabs-demo%2F&module=%2Fsrc%2Fpages%2Fmdx-tabs-demo.mdx&theme=dark